# Why isn't jquery-ui's extended position() method working with SVG elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, position

jQuery UI overrides jQuery's `position` method with [its own](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/), which, as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CbPC/), allows me to display an icon in the top-right corner of a `<div>` quite easily:

```
icon.position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "right top",
    of: "div"
});
```

However, in the case of SVG elements (e.g. `<rect>`), I get unexpected behaviour.  For example, as you can see in this test case, the icon shows up around the top left, rather than top right; if you try it with "left top" instead, the icon is positioned off screen.

I've searched this site and Google as best I could, but I could find no reference to jQuery UI's position method not working with SVG elements.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is not very good for working with SVG, especially when dealing with positions. 
In SVG you can have rotations, scaling, transformation matrix and all sorts of crazy stuff. What if the rect is rotated with 45 degrees....what would be the meaning of "right top" or "bottom" ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qjmkc/

Comment: I would expect the semantics of those positions to be relative to the bounding box of the element in question, I guess.  That works as expected in "standard" situations, while being at least deterministic in "odd" situations.  Is that not better than the seemingly arbitrary behaviour I'm seeing here?

Comment: That's interesting, but not all that relevant, as we're talking about jQuery UI here, not jQuery.  

Just to be clear, I understand and fully accept that the behaviour of jQuery UI's `position` method, in the case of an SVG element (e.g. `<rect>`) being *positioned*, would be undefined, but I'm not seeing any reason for the positioning of a non-SVG element (e.g. `<span>`) *relative to* an SVG element to be broken.

Comment: hey man, it's not my fault this stuff is not working...i'm not your enemy here. But mixing html and svg...that's a bad dream. So is using jQuery for svg manipulation (or jQuery UI, whatever...that's still build on jQuery, "This plugin extends jQuery's built-in .position() method" - according to the documentation).

Comment: Maybe this is just a question of terminology, but once again, I do not intend to *manipulate* any SVG in any way.  I was just hoping this function could figure out where an already-rendered SVG element is on the page, which seems like it wouldn't be any more difficult than any other element.  Thanks for you help.